# php fetchpage() function help, identifying image sizes from a url in php

Tags: php

hey guys so im building an application and one of teh features it will have is the ability to show photo links from twitter inline sort of like what tweetdeck has done in their chrome browser version and sites like crowdreel have been able to do, i spent some time researching how to grab image tags from urls on google and found this fantastic script http://www.bitrepository.com/extract-images-from-an-url.html

the script is great and does exactly what i need, however now my challenge is that the array returned from the links returns every image in the page including thumbnails ads etc, so a link to a page like this: http://lockerz.com/s/69901787

will return an array with quite a few image links to sort through,
however what i need is a link to the main image so that i can display it inline with tweets, my idea is that i run some sort of code to figure out which of the images in the page is the largest? what are your thoughts on this? is this the right method or is there something easier thats built into php perhaps? thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the links to the images you can pass them to the  [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function in PHP.

Look at this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#example-2267

Comment: ahhh this is fantastic!!! alright so last question then is what would be the best way to then compare the image sizes to find out which of the group is the largest? im sure its something i already have learned but cant think of it off the top of my head, i assume one of the sorting methods perhaps? thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped! To find the largest image, it depends whether you're looking for the image with the largest area or just height or width.. In any case you have to take the values from index positions 0 and 1 of the array that getimagesize() returns for each image and put them in separate width, height or area arrays and sort them: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: `getimagesize()` would download the entire image, however, and then you'd throw away that data after getting the image's specs. A "cheaper" alternative would be to grab only the first 512bytes or so of the image, and do your own parseing to identify type/size from image's header.

Comment: interesting, but how would i go about doing this?